# How do I get DateTime from mysql and set it to json format ready for highcharts

Tags: mysql, json, highcharts

I started my project March last year and have almost got it right.
Trying to get data from mysql and put it in highcharts.
This is my query

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","manortsc_test");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sth = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT DateTime,max(T)
    FROM alldata
    WHERE DATE(DateTime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY hour(DateTime)

    "
    );
    $rows = array();
    $rows['name'] = 'Outside';
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
        $rows['data'][] = $r['max(T)'];
}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The json output is missing the date and time

[{"name":"Outside","data":[17.5,16.3,15.6,15.1,14.4,14,14.1,16,18.5,21.7,24.1,26.9,28.3,29.6,30.6,31.1,31.8]}]

The graph shows okay (except datetime on x axis) and I cannot figure how to fix it. I have tried every way except the correct way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL has a function for format dates https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: the date and time is  formatted as 2016-02-25 12:38:34. I just do not know how to query the datetime and store it in the json format

Comment: If I add code like this $date1 = strtotime($row['DateTime']; then the output looks like this, but no chart at all now.

{"name1":"temperature","data1":[[1483484492,"17.5"],[1483488113,"16.3"],[1483491734,"15.6"],[1483495353,"15.1"],[1483498974,"14.4"],[1483502596,"14.0"],[1483506218,"14.1"],[1483509838,"16.0"],[1483513459,"18.5"],[1483517078,"21.7"],[1483520400,"24.1"],[1483524022,"26.9"],[1483527643,"28.3"],[1483531263,"29.6"],[1483534885,"30.6"],[1483538505,"31.1"],[1483542124,"31.8"]]}

Comment: You need to have the dates in javascript notation which is epoch * 1000. Now, the reason you have no data showing is that your `y` values are all strings: `[1483484492,"17.5"]` - "17.5" isn't a number. You need to convert your `y` values to numbers (many different ways to do this).

Comment: I see what you mean. Will research how to do that. Thanks

Comment: I converted the max temperature string to a number by using $maxt = 1 * $row['max(T)']; Is that a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the query to this and now it works.

Thanks wergeld and Yuri for the assistance.

```
     $sth = mysqli_query($con,"
        SELECT DateTime,max(T)
        FROM davisvp
        WHERE DATE(DateTime) = CURDATE()
        GROUP BY hour(DateTime)
       "
      );
      $result = array();
      $result['name'] = 'temperature';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth))
      {
        $date = strtotime($row['DateTime']);
        $maxt = 1 * $row['max(T)'];
        $result1 = array();
        array_push($result1,$date);
        array_push($result1,$maxt);
        $result['data'][] = $result1;
      }
      echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```